# Html.Deserialize loses TempData after browser refresh

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-futures

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 wizard. To pass one big viewmodel from step to step I use the futures assembly. I serialize my model with

```
@Html.Serialize("model", Model, SerializationMode.Signed);
```

and deserialize it in the controllers

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var serialized = Request.Form["model"];
    if (serialized != null)
    {
        model = (BausparViewModel)new MvcSerializer().Deserialize(serialized, SerializationMode.Signed);
        TryUpdateModel(model);
    }

...
}
```

I set the TempData in the

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
        TempData["model"] = model;
}
```

Every wizard step has it's own view and I manage previous/next actions in the controller with RedirectToAction("ActionName")

Everything works fine, as long as the browser gets no refresh by using F5 or the menu. On this point the controller gets called again. The controller already has a model,although the TempData doesn't get saved again.

But there are two enum properties missing. They are used in previous steps. They got bound to the view via RadiobuttonFor.

So why is there a model which is incomplete?

Thanks in advance
csteinmueller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything that should live longer than 1 request, you should not use `TempData`. Use `Session` or some other longer term storage mechanism.

`TempData` is designed to delete a value after it is read out of the dictionary. That's why `TempDataDictionary` has methods like `Peek` and `Keep`. Those methods let you tell the dictionary explicitly "hey, don't delete this value after I read it", because by default, it does delete the value after you read it.

Comment: Calling the Keep methods works in this case. The howto in mvc3 wizards i've read used the TempData. Isn't a session user based? Because it could be possible that one user instantiates mutliple wizards. It is a consulting application for external partners.

Comment: Yes, Session is per user. However, TempData uses Session as its underlying data store (by default), so it is also per user. If you want to allow a user to spawn multiple wizards, you should manage those separate wizards at the application level (for example, store a Wizard[] array in session or TempData if you choose to keep using that).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on TempData and Session. At the moment I was too lazy to read into tempdata. It was suggested by the mvc3 wizard tutorial. I'll accept the answer in combination with the Wizard array in tempdata or session. I think it will solve my problem.